# TypeScript interface type info (generated)

Tags: typescript, types

I generate TypeScript definitions from some C# classes.
I would like to have the C# class' type at the JavaScript side as well, thus I'm putting it as string into a Type property:

```
// C#
public class MyBase
{
    public string Type => this.GetType().Name;
}
```

I would like to have this type information at TypeScript level as well:

```
// TypeScript
interface MyBase {
    type: "MyBase"
}
```

The problem with the above approach is it can't handle inheritence:

```
// C#
public class MyDescendant : MyBase
{
}

// TypeScript
interface MyDescendant extends MyBase {
    type: "MyDescendant" // <-- ERROR: TS2430: Type '"MyDescendant"' is not assignable to type '"MyBase"'
}
```

If the generated `type` properties were of types `"MyBase" | string` in the base and `"MyDescendant" | string` in the descendant, it would compile, intellisense would also work, but there would be no compile time error at the usages (possibly existing TypeGuard functions for these types) in case someone renamed the C# class.

How to generate the `type`s to have this type safety as well?

Comment: Why do you need the `type` property to have the literal string type e.g. `"MyBase"` rather than just `string`? In C# it's just typed as a string

Comment: It holds the C# class name. I would like to write TypeGuards for these generated classes, and want them to be safe for C# refactors. Like: `function IsMyDescendant(arg): arg is MyDescendant{ return arg && (arg as MyDescendant).type === "MyDescendant"; }`. Here the string "MyDescendant", if the class name changes from MyDescendant to AnythingElse, will produce a compile error

Comment: To check whether something is an instance of a class, you can always use `instanceof` in JavaScript. E.g. `arg instanceof MyDescendant`. That's a sort of "built-in" type guard for classes

Comment: We always genereate *interfaces* from C# classes (no JS footprint). The data coming from server is JSON, there won't be any JS class instances

Comment: That makes sense. It feels like you would need a generic `MyBase` so that you could have something like `interface MyBase<Type extends string> { type: Type }`. Then `MyDescendant` could be `interface MyDescendant extends MyBase<"MyDescendant"> {}`. Don't know if that's feasible for your use-case with generated code though.

Comment: Thanks, this idea can be useful. The current code generator can't do this at the moment, but I think we can extend it for the task.